# progress bar positioning

Tags: gwt, xtk

@haehn Hi Haehn

I'm using GWT with XTK. And I have been successful in using "min-height:100%" trick in the  to get XTK going in the GWT app. Now everything is working, except the fact that the progress bar is positioned right below the black area.

In one of the posts you mentioned something about using position:relative to make it appear in the center of the black area. But that trick didnt help me in my case. Actually, I'm not quite sure if I followed your explanation properly in that post. A quick glance through the XTK code base didn't light any blubs either.

A little help here?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a new way to define CSS for the progress bar: overload the CSS class `xtk-progress-bar`. Any style gets automatically applied to the progress bar.

Comment: also check out this xtk issue #94 on github for more info: https://github.com/xtk/X/issues/94

Answer (score 0):

this is a tough one - you have to play with the css style. if you figure out the problem, please let us know!

Comment: Hi haehn (XTK) - please consider making progressbar object Public in Renderer object, so that we can get a handle to it and re-position it to the middle of screen. OR an ability to override the css style of the progressbar. Right now progressbar object is protected and its style is not overideable. If I'm mistaken, please suggest how I can re-position the progressbar to the middle of the screen. Thank you.

Comment: Hi XTK. Can you please comment on this issue? is there any thought being given to how progressbar can made more accesible in the client code? one suggestion is to publish js events from the framework about the progress and let "power users" render progressbars themselves. for other users xtk should make the progressbar css more overideable. In my usecase (in xtk with gwt), progressbar appears out of my desktop screen :). my current work around is to show spinning ajax gif image until onshow() is called. problem with this approach is user does not know % progress. Thank you.